# How to get a UK driving license as a non-UK national if your passport is with the Home Office?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license, passport

I am living in the UK and my passport is at the Home Office for a extension as a partner of an EU national. Some issue came up and I was sent back the document and I have to send them back. My problem is that I cannot drive; it has been 2 years since I originally left. I just have my Social Security number and I work full time. Is there any way I can get my license as I don't have my home country license as well?

Comment: Are you asking what you can use for identification in order to obtain a UK driving license?

Comment: As per website i do need one of following or [all](https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-provisional-driving-licence#before-you-start) as i just got a old passort photocopy and SS #, so yes @Dorothy

Comment: @Nofel the writing on the website (https://www.gov.uk/id-for-driving-licence) implies that you need to send all, but that can't be the actual requirement, because most people won't be eligible to have all of those documents.  For example, foreigners will not have a naturalization certificate, and British citizens who aren't dual nationals won't have an EU/EEA national ID card.  So if you have a BRP, you can use that.

Comment: @phoog don't think ig to BRP, though i remember application for it from post office.

Comment: Also note that, if you have a biometric passport, [you don’t need to send your biometric passport in with your application, use the 9-digit passport number instead.](https://www.gov.uk/id-for-driving-licence).

Comment: @Dorothy Nofel cannot possibly have a biometric UK passport if applying for extension as a partner of an EEA national.

Comment: @phoog not UK passport, but that from another country, as suggested by both this, and the earlier Q.

Comment: @Dorothy but the option of sending only the passport number applies only to UK biometric passports. Perhaps you overlooked that? Copy-paste quote: *You must send in an identity document with your application unless you have a valid UK biometric passport (where the photograph and signature are on the same page).*

Comment: @phoog; indeed I did might that vital bit; thx.

Comment: So i think i cannot apply

Answer (score 1):

You [must send in an original ID document](https://www.gov.uk/id-for-driving-licence) with your application for a UK driving license.

> You must send in an identity document with your application unless you have a valid UK biometric passport (where the photograph and signature are on the same page).
>
> [...]
>
> You must send the following identity documents if you don’t have a biometric passport:
>
> - a current and valid passport
> - a biometric residence permit (BRP) - formerly known as the identity card for foreign nationals
> - an European Union (EU) or European Economic Area (EEA) national identity card
> - a travel document
>
> You must send the original document with your driving licence application.
>
> If you don’t have an EU or EEA passport, you’ll need to send in a visa that proves you have permission to live in the UK.
>
> You can’t use:
>
> - photocopies or laminated certificates
> - certified copies - including those certified by the [Post Office document certification service](http://www.postoffice.co.uk/document-certification-service)
>
> Don’t send in your passport if you need it within the next month - consider delaying your driving licence application until after you’ve travelled.

If your passport is blocked by your other application and you do not have another means of ID listed above, then yes, you will have to wait.